# Why do I get a KeyError on a Model in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am getting a KeyError: 'conversation' on the line `conv = ans.conversation` in the code section:

```
answers = Answers.objects.all()

for ans in answers:
    conv = ans.conversation
    ...
```

My model 'Answers' looks like this:

```
class Answers(models.Model):
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation)
    ...
```

I get the error sometimes, so if I run the code, I get the correct result a few times, but eventually within the for loop, sometimes the line `conv = ans.conversation` fails. Why do you think an error like this could ocurr?

The entire error trace is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 164, in _get_
    rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/mixins.py", line 13, in get_cached_value
    return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]
KeyError: 'conversation'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/webapps/municipio/municipio/reportes/views.py", line 153, in get_whats_data
    conv = ans.conversation
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 178, in _get_
    rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 145, in get_object
    return qs.get(self.field.get_reverse_related_filter(instance))
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 402, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in _len_
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in _iter_
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 226, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
  File "/webapps/municipio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 196, in handle_abort
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
```

Comment: Sounds like a system issue, not a code problem. What happens if you change the database to PosgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

The KeyError is internally anticipated by Django and is handled to obtain a default.

In your case, there is no default so if the field is accessed when a value has not been supplied for the conversation field at creation you will see this KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and the problem was that, in one of my `ExampleModel` instances, there was a value for a *foreign key field* that was referencing to some invalid record, and it might happened because when I deleted this record, the foreign key referencing it remained as before and has not been set to `NULL` or has not been removed.

So, for example I have this model `ExampleModel`, that has a *foreign key* field with name of `neighbour` referencing some id in model `NeighbourModel`, and I have an instance of `NeighbourModel` that has some data, and I will create an instance of `ExampleModel` which it's `neighbour` field is pointing to the `NeighbourModel` instance, and when I try to delete the `NeighbourModel` instance, the `neighbour` field of my `ExampleModel` instance remains the same (which mustn't remain, this might be due to some error or misunderstanding between the django ORM and the database type you are using, e.g. sqlite, or I don't know you may instructed the model to behave that way), then the django system will try to find that `NeighbourModel` instance in the database using some query when you try to call this field, and the database returns nothing, and finally django raises some error telling that this id is not valid or this record does not exist.

**Solutions**

1. You may try to check the `on_delete` property of your model's foreign key field, and give it some appropriate value.
2. Check if the database type accepts it and do whatever this `on_delete` property says.
3. Try to avoid foreign key field values that are pointing to some empty space (record).

I think this might happen with sqlite, you can also try different database types to know if this is the case.