# Recursion error caused by __init__ method

Tags: python, django, django-models, init

I have a model Folder which has a ForeignKey refering to itself in order to represent a folders structure :

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    folder_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent_folder = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Folder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.pk is not None:
            self.initial_filepath = self.filepath()

    def filepath(self):
        if not self.parent_folder:
            return f'media/scripts/{self.folder_name}'
        else:
            return f'{self.parent_folder.filepath()}/{self.folder_name}'
```

The issue is, when deleting a folder that has childrens in the admin panel, a recursion error occurs. I was able to determine that it was coming from the `filepath` method called in the `__init__` one. However, what I don't understand, is why this is happening as I don't really understand how the `__init__` method work.

I'd be glad if someone could help me understand how I could go about dealing with this issue, as I'm currently lost as to what to do.

**Here's a glimpse of the unending traceback** :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stephane.bernardelli\Documents\ScriptsApp\.env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 187, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)
  File "C:\Users\stephane.bernardelli\Documents\ScriptsApp\.env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\mixins.py", line 15, in get_cached_value
    return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]
KeyError: 'parent_folder'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

**Exact same error repeating till a recursion error occurs**
```

And when the recursion error occurs, I have a long message (too long for me to put it entirely) in which I found that :

```
File "C:\Users\stephane.bernardelli\Documents\ScriptsApp\src\scripts\models.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.initial_filepath = self.filepath()
  File "C:\Users\stephane.bernardelli\Documents\ScriptsApp\src\scripts\models.py", line 48, in filepath
    if not self.parent_folder:
  File "C:\Users\stephane.bernardelli\Documents\ScriptsApp\.env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 189, in __get__
    has_value = None not in self.field.get_local_related_value(instance)
  File "C:\Users\stephane.bernardelli\Documents\ScriptsApp\.env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 742, in get_local_related_value
    return self.get_instance_value_for_fields(instance, self.local_related_fields)
  File "C:\Users\stephane.bernardelli\Documents\ScriptsApp\.env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 764, in get_instance_value_for_fields
    ret.append(getattr(instance, field.attname))
```

**admin.py**

```
class FolderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):        
    fieldsets = [
        (None,            {'fields': ['folder_name']}),
        ('Parent Folder', {'fields': ['parent_folder']}),
    ]
    
    list_display = ('folder_name', 'parent_folder')

admin.site.register(Folder, FolderAdmin)
```

Comment: You just need to register it in `admin.py`, I've added the code to do it.
Then just create 2 folders, with one a child of the other, and try to delete the parent, you'll get the error.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? There may be something that you're not seeing right now, that could be helpful.

Comment: It's 2k words long so I put it on [this codeshare](https://codeshare.io/traceback). It's just the same thing repeating over and over but at least you have everything you could ask for.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61000782/why-do-i-get-a-keyerror-on-a-model-in-django, it happens because there's no default value supplied  in the field. Django anticipates the KeyError internally and uses it to obtain a default value, but if it's not supplied, the exception is raised.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll deal with it with that in mind